# remove prefix and suffix from the file with mv

Tags: linux, rename, mv

I have a directory which contains multiple files. I need to rename these files.

This is how the file names looks like:

```
snap-file-name-1.txt
snap-file-name-2.txt
snap-file-name-3.txt
```

I need to remove "snap" and ".txt" from these files.

```
-file-name-1
-file-name-2
-file-name-3
```

How do I do that with `mv` command?

Comment: have you tried `rename` command?

Comment: i tried but it did not work: rename `rename 's/\.txt$//' *.*`

Answer (score 1):

Use sed to manipulate the file name:

```
ls | while read file; do
    mv -- ${file} $(sed -n 's/snap\(.*\).txt/\1/p' <<<${file})
done
```

Answer (score 0):

With Bash you could do something like this to rename those files:

```
#!/bin/bash
files=$(find -type f -name 'snap-file-name-*.txt')
for f in $files
do
  mv "$f" "$(echo $f | sed -n 's/snap\(.*\).txt/\1/p')"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `rename` command with specific regex pattern:

```
rename 's/snap([-a-z0-9]+)\.txt$/$1/' *.*
```